# Rails Capybara RSpec XPath CSS selector is only using children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec, capybara

I using Cucumber and RSpec to check whether the `div` in yellow has the class `card-selected`.

[image: asdf]

The code I'm writing is

```
node = page.find(:css, '.card-selected')
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[7]">
```

If I copy the retured XPath in Chrome, I get the yellow div selected, as expected.

The problem comes with querying the node for its CSS attributes. As I understand, this is not the expected behavior:

```
# Checking for current node contents
node.has_css?('.card-selected')
false

node.has_selector?(:css, '.card-selected')
false

node.has_css?('.card-contents')
true
```

However, if I query the parent of the node

```
# Checking for parent node contents
node.find(:xpath, '..').has_css?('.card-selected')
true

node.find(:xpath, '..').has_css?('.card-deselected')
true

node.find(:xpath, '..').has_css?('.card-contents')
true
```

From this behavior, `has_css?` method seems to be checking for the children contents only, but not the node itself. I can't seem to find a workaround as querying the parent will make matching too complicated.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: In addition, node.visible? returns true

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is expected - finders find within the current scope element, and the has_xxx? methods are the same.  They check whether or not the current scope element contains elements matching the passed selector. What you want is `matches_selector?`

```
node.matches_selector?(:css, '.card-selected') # the :css is optional if it's the default selector type
```

or in an expect form

```
expect(node).to match_css('.card-selected')
```

Comment: If finders find within the current scope, shouldn't the first `node.has_css?('.card-selected')` return `true` instead? `.card-selected` belongs to the `node`

Comment: @EstebanBouza No - within as in contained within  - descendants -children, grand-children, etc.

Comment: Capybara docs say this:
`http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FMatchers%3Ahas_css%253F`
`#has_css?(path, options = {}) ⇒ Boolean`
`Checks if a given CSS selector is on the page or current node.`

As I understand, the current `node` does have `.card-selected` css, so I still think the behavior is not expected.

Comment: @EstebanBouza I've told you what the behavior of Capybara is, and told you the methods you need to use to do what you're trying to do.  You are free to believe me or not.

Comment: Thanks @TomWalpole. My purpose here was to understand the behavior from this Capybara methods, which I still fail to understand. For now I have used a workaround to check for css properties using xpath instead.